# Chrome NaCl - using link against existing DLL

Tags: dll, google-nativeclient

I'm currently trying to get Google's NaCl running with an existing DLL. Recompiling the DLL from source is not an option due to licensing issues. Is there any way to get the existing DLL loaded and it's methods run?

Best regards,
bash0r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. NaCl is a sandboxing technology that needs to recompile code according to strict rules that prevent the code from escaping the sandbox. If you can't compile the source, you can't put it in the sandbox.

You might be able to wrap the DLL in a native executable that exposes the functionality as a [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)-compatible binary, then communicate with it that way. By design, this solution isn't going to allow wide deployment of your product using the Chrome Web Store, because it contains a Windows binary, which CWS doesn't distribute.